# How to extent the logout time when doc is opened for edit/view sharepoint site?

Tags: document-library, javascript, time-out

I have custom javascript to logout the sharepoint page after 30 minutes. Now the problem is, if i have opened any document from shared document to edit/view. then also sharepoint site got logged out after 30 minutes. Is that possible to extent/stop logged out when some document is openeed from sharepoint site.
Like in javascript if any document is opened it has to return some value so that we can check and do some timerjob activity ot extend the time.
Note: In javascript logic i have return like if the page is not refreshed till 30 minute it will automatically redirect to the signout page.

Comment: You asked this on StackOverflow too. Why?

Comment: @rjcup3 still not got an reply that y.